# Как получить доступ к данным безымянного массива json

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Проблема заключается в следующем: есть NetworkManager , который я использую во многих приложениях , где присутствует работа с API. Всегда до этого у массива json было имя , по которому я получал данные , например:

```
 "weather": [
    {
      "id": 804,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "overcast clouds",
      "icon": "04d"
    }
  ]
```

В данный момент я работаю с массивом без имени:

```
[
  {
    "r030": 36,
    "txt": "Австралійський долар",
    "rate": 20.9822,
    "cc": "AUD",
    "exchangedate": "07.12.2020"
  }]
```

Непосредственно NetworkManager

```
func getAllCurrency(value: String, completion: (([Model]) -> Void)?) {
    AF.request(self.baseURL + value, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).response
    { (responseData) in
        guard let data = responseData.data else {return}
        do {
            
            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [String: Any], let results = jsonArray[""] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
            var currency = [Model]()
            results.forEach({ currency.append(Model(with: $0)) })
            print(currency.count)
            completion?(currency)
        } catch {
            print("Error decoding == \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Я подозреваю , что нужно поменять данную строку , так как в скобках после jsonArray , до этого всегда указывал имя массива:

```
let results = jsonArray[""] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю можно это сделать через конвертацию ответа сервера в класс-модель. У Alamofire есть такая штука:

```
AF.request("link request", method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                
            case.failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```

для этого делаем класс-модель:

```
struct DummyData: Codable {
    let r030: Int
    let txt, cc, exchangedate: String
    let rate: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case r030, txt,cc,rate
    }
}
```

и на выходе вы получаете список:

```
do {
    //here dataResponse received from a network request
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let model = try decoder.decode([DummyData].self, from:
                 dataResponse) //Decode JSON Response Data 
    print(model)
} catch let parsingError {
    print("Error", parsingError)
}
```

[Вот есть хорошая статья](https://medium.com/better-programming/json-parsing-in-swift-2498099b78f) на тему парсинга в swift